# Embedding of $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semidirect-product

In a certain exercise I am asked to prove something that involves semidirect product. I wanted to know if $\mathbb{Z}$ could be embedded in a semidirect product of bigger groups, named for example $A,B$, this is, if there exists, $A,B$ so that $\mathbb{Z} < A\rtimes_{\theta} B$ for some $\theta: B \rightarrow Aut(A)$. Is it possible to simply assume this?

Comment: You can clearly do this for any group $A$ or any group $B$ that has ${\mathbb Z}$ as a subgroup (or equivalently has an element of infinite order).

Comment: ... or when in the new group $G=\mathbb{Z} < A\rtimes_{\theta} B$ there is an element of infinite order $g$, the injective group map being $n\to g^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any direct product is a semidirect product, so just take

$$\Bbb Z(\cong\circ \le)\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z_2,$$

where $(\cong\circ \le)$ means "isomorphic to a subgroup of".

---

Less glib, look at the semidirect products of $\Bbb Z$ with itself, discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3094131/104041).